# Does the InheritedWidget's updateShouldNotify need to exist?

Tags: flutter, inherited-widget

The official comment of updateShouldNotify says it can control the InheritedWidget's child build or not when the InheritedWidget is rebuild.

```
  /// Whether the framework should notify widgets that inherit from this widget.
  ///
  /// When this widget is rebuilt, sometimes we need to rebuild the widgets that
  /// inherit from this widget but sometimes we do not. For example, if the data
  /// held by this widget is the same as the data held by `oldWidget`, then we
  /// do not need to rebuild the widgets that inherited the data held by
  /// `oldWidget`.
  ///
  /// The framework distinguishes these cases by calling this function with the
  /// widget that previously occupied this location in the tree as an argument.
  /// The given widget is guaranteed to have the same [runtimeType] as this
  /// object.


@protected
  bool updateShouldNotify(covariant InheritedWidget oldWidget);
```

But **if the InheritedWidget is rebuilt , then all the widgets inherited from the this widget will rebuilt** no matter this updateShouldNotify is return false or true. **because these widgets are the children of the InheritedWidget** .

Can anybody give an example of children do not rebuild with updateShouldNotify when the InheritedWidget is rebuilt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give you a simple example: how can a `const` child widget of the `InheritedWidget` ever be rebuilt if it is never notified?

Run this sample code to see the behavior. Change the return value of `updateShouldNotify` from `false` to `true` and then tap on the button.

```
/// This is the [StatefulWidget] that will rebuild the [InheritedWidget].
class InheritedParent extends StatefulWidget {
  const InheritedParent({super.key});

  @override
  State<InheritedParent> createState() => _InheritedParentState();
}

class _InheritedParentState extends State<InheritedParent> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Inherited(
      /// Pass the random color to the [InheritedWidget].
      color: _getRandomColor(),
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            /// The inherited child is constant.
            const InheritedChild(),
            FloatingActionButton(
              /// We call setState, so the entire subtree should be rebuilt...
              /// but what about 'const InheritedChild()'?
              onPressed: () => setState(() {}),
              child: const Icon(Icons.add),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  /// This method will return a random color.
  Color _getRandomColor() {
    return Colors.primaries[math.Random().nextInt(Colors.primaries.length)];
  }
}

/// The widget that provides a [Color] to its descendants through the context.
class Inherited extends InheritedWidget {
  const Inherited({
    super.key,
    required this.color,
    required super.child,
  });

  final Color color;

  static Inherited? of(BuildContext context) {
    return context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<Inherited>();
  }

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(Inherited oldWidget) {
    /// Change this to see the behavior.
    return false;
  }
}

class InheritedChild extends StatefulWidget {
  const InheritedChild({super.key});

  @override
  State<InheritedChild> createState() => _InheritedChildState();
}

class _InheritedChildState extends State<InheritedChild> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 128.0,
      height: 128.0,
      /// Access the color specified in 'Inherited'.
      color: Inherited.of(context)?.color,
    );
  }
}
```

The `InheritedWidget` allows you to filter rebuilds (calls to `setState` so that descendants are only rebuilt when any data that they depend on (from the parent InheritedWidget) changes.

While the convenience idiom is to provide a static `of(context)` method for your inherited widgets, remember that they can be used without one; to make it explicit:

```
class _InheritedChildState extends State<InheritedChild> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 128.0,
      height: 128.0,
      /// This widget DEPENDS on the [Inherited] to rebuild.
      color: context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<Inherited>()?.color,
    );
  }
}
```

From the documentation: "Returns the nearest widget of the given type T and creates a dependency on it".

When a dependency is created, the child widget is registered for changes. When does it get notified of the changes?

When `updateShouldNotify` return `true`.

Therefore, the correct implementation of `Inherited.updateShouldNotify` is:

```
@override
bool updateShouldNotify(Inherited oldWidget) {
  /// The data that the child widget depends on in order to properly
  /// build itself.
  return oldWidget.color != color;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @offworldwelcome , so updateShouldNotify only work with const widget rebuilding? maybe remove the const directive can do the same work?

Comment: or the main purpose of updateShouldNotify is to remove the unnecessarily rebuild of inheriwidget'children ? ( and must work with const directive for the child)

Comment: @ximmyxiao InheritedWidgets allow you to share data in a tree (any child widget can call `Inherited.of(context)` to access data. Another benefit is that this allows you to instantiate `const` widgets that will only rebuild when the data they depend on changes; for example, the `provider` package uses `InheritedWidget` under the hood. To answer your question: this is an optimization that allows you to minimize rebuilds as well as target specific sections of your widget tree for rebuild, instead of having to rebuild the entire tree.